# UART IO not working, placed multimeter to measure voltage and IO began working instantly - why?

Tags: power-supply, uart, discharge, electrostatic, simcom

We are a bit stumped on this and wanted to see if anyone had any experience or perspective on this.

**Description of Event**

We are communicating via UART from a 3.3V processor to a Sim7000G (1.6-1.8v).  At one point yesterday we experienced a failure of communication between the processor and the 7000G.  Literally no communication.

We disconnected the battery, unplugged all power sources, etc...  Upon reconnection, we still had the issue.  After trying several different power sources, power cables, batteries, the issue simply wouldn't go away (after working fine for days).  However, we can see the Sim7000 is powering on as it's powerkey light is turning on (we have the pin tied to an LED).

So, we pull out the multimeter as a basic check to verify there's voltage.  First check, the battery level.  The second we placed the multimeter from Battery to Ground, the communication resumed perfectly fine.

Pull the multimeter off, communication stops.  Put it on again, communication resumes - but now continues whether the multimeter is connected or not.  A day later we have not encountered this again and can't repeat it.

**Circuit Breakdown**

We are not using a bidirectional level shifter yet (like NTS0104PW,118) and this issue may be solved by that moving over to that.

To step the voltage down form the processor to the 7000G we are just using a simple voltage divider (2 resistors).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3UAb2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To step the voltage up from the Sim7000G to the processor, we use a two-transistor level shifter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiKsxM.png)</sup>

The Sim7000G is powered like this. *This is a somewhat simplified circuit, as we the battery is used for other things and ties into the main circuitry as well - which we understand could also be where the issue*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMojJH.png)</sup>

We really appreciate anyone's time, answers, and suggestions on this.

Comment: Your MOSFET symbols are labeled NPN.  Are they really MOSFETs or BJTs?  If they are MOSFETs (which I suspect) can you provide a datasheet or at least a part number? Do you have a scope that can look at the actual signal levels between the devices?

Comment: Did you make sure there all the grounds are connected proper?

Comment: @evildemonic - they are Mosfets.  The part number is FDV303N.  We usually used a different part but they've been out of stock for months.

We've put a scope on the lines to ensure voltage levels are good and they are within the tolerance, though we will be looking at it again more closely.

Comment: @MituRaj - Yeah the grounds are all good.  It's a PCB we've assembled with a pick-n-place and have been using it for a few months without any issues.

Comment: You might not have enough gate drive.  It may be just on the verge of working, and that could explain your symptoms.  Scope the signals, I bet your edges look terrible.

Comment: What is the baudrate?

Comment: @evildemonic Thank you for the suggestion, we will look into that more closely.  We have the footprint for a bidirectional translator on the board (NTS0104PW,118‎) as well, so we use that for for UART communication and test more.  I really appreciate your input.

Comment: @MituRaj We are using 115200

Comment: From mosfet datasheet, it looks like 1.8V is not enough at the gate to drive it.

Comment: 115200 baud through 10k resistance at 1.8/3.3v? I wouldn't have even tried that, just assumed it could not possibly work.  At lower voltages, noise is an even bigger issue, so needs *strong* drive pulses. Maybe it'll work at a reduced baud rate.

Comment: @MituRaj Looking at it now I'm sure you are correct.  We were using a different transistor in design, but the inventory issues lately we had to switch transistors.  I think the we mixed up gate as 3.3v not 1.8v when replacing the part.  Thanks all!

Comment: @rdtsc Thanks for the info, very helpful.  We are switching to a bidirectional level shifter, which has a footprint on the board already.

Comment: @rdtsc Yah, some people do. I had an EE. who puts 15k everywhere to protect his circuitry. I just had to stare at him but nothing else, because he was proud of doing so. "How inspiring?".